# Reading Incoming Mbit/s in plaintext with Perl

Tags: perl, unix, networking

I cant find ANY solution for this, i want to read the incoming Mbit/s on a interface in perl.
I am just trying to make the perl script report the Mbit/s as: 9.66
That would be as if i have an incoming network of 9.66 Mbit/s.

I tried to use VNstat and parse out the chars. but no avail.

Comment: You might take a look at the [Net::Pcap](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Pcap) module. Here's an [article](http://www.drdobbs.com/web-development/monitoring-network-traffic-with-netpcap/184416128) describing how to use it; you may be able to adapt it to get throughput.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Linux system, the /sys/ directory usually has sub-directories like this:

```
/sys/class/net/eth0/statistics
```

If you can rely on that existing consistently (/sys/ was added in kernel 2, so you should be fine), the "files" in that directory contain information that you could use to build some stats on an interface, including incoming (rx) bytes to that interface.

Here is an *extremely* crude example:

```
use List::Util qw(sum);
my @bytes;
for(1..11) {
    open(FH, "<", "/sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes") or die $@;
    push(@bytes, <FH>);
    sleep 1;
    close(FH);
}
my @bytes_per_second;
for(1..10) {
    my $diff = ($bytes[$_] - $bytes[($_ - 1)]);
    push(@bytes_per_second, $diff);
}
print sum(@bytes_per_second)/@bytes_per_second;
```

The code above will give you an average [in bytes] of (roughly) per second incoming data to the interface named "eth0". There are a lot of good ways to make this better that I didn't feel were necessary for this demonstration, but include using a timer and reading from the file differently.

Hopefully this will provide something usable to you, but if you're not even on Linux, then unfortunately this will be completely unhelpful.